# Which type of regression should i use for output having 3-4 states?

Tags: statistics, regression, logistic-regression

If output has 2 states, we can use logistics regression. But which type of regression to use when there are 3-4 output states?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

One choice is multinomial logistic regression, where the sigmoid is replaced by a softmax.